# How can I allow an element to overflow when it is nested inside an element set to display: block?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table and I need the table-body to have vertical scrolling.

I also have some `td` elements inside the table that I would like to expand on hover and overflow the whole table.

```
.element:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform: scale(6, 6);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

Everything behaves as expected until I set

```
tbody { display: block }
```

As far as I know, this is the only way to get the `tbody` to scroll. But when adding this in, the `td` element no longer overflows the table on hover and instead gets hidden behind the `thead`.

I have tried to solve it by adding relative and absolute position but it didn't seem to make any difference... I have also tried changing the z-index to -1 on the `thead` and this didn't solve it either.

If you run the snippet below, and you hover over the `td` item with a green background, this is the behavior I am looking for. You can see that it overflows the entire table on hover. But this version does not have scrolling in the `tbody`.

```css
tbody {
  height: 200px;
  /*   display: block; */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.element {
  background-color: green;
}

.element:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform: scale(6, 6);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card col-8 offset-2 p-0 mt-5">
  <div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">#</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">First</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Second</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Third</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">1</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3 element">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">2</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">3</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">4</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">5</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">6</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

But now if you run this next snippet with the `tbody` scrolling enabled, you can see that when hovering over the green `td` item, it is now hidden behind the `thead`.

```css
tbody {
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.element {
  background-color: green;
}

.element:hover {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform: scale(6, 6);
  transform-origin: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card col-8 offset-2 p-0 mt-5">
  <div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">#</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">First</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Second</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Third</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">1</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3 element">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">2</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">3</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">4</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">5</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">6</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `td` element is eventually going to be an image, which is why I don't want it getting cut off behind the `thead`.

How can I get the behavior I want and allow the element to overflow the entire table, but also have vertical scrolling on the `tbody`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use css **`transform-origin`** Property to achieve that particular requirement.

```
.element:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 999;

    transform-origin: 54% 14%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `td` is hidden behind your `thead` **because** of the overflow on the `tbody`. Set your overflow on the container of your table instead of the `tbody` and see if that works for you.

```css
.card-body {
    /* Instead of tbody */
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.element {
    background-color: green;
}

.element:hover {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transform: scale(6, 6);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card col-8 offset-2 p-0 mt-5">
  <div class="card-body p-0">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">#</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">First</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Second</th>
          <th class="col-3" scope="col">Third</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">1</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3 element">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">2</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">3</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">4</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">5</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row m-0">
          <th class="col-3" scope="row">6</th>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
          <td class="col-3">Blah</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```